# "go get" command not generating the bin folder when it is run in a shell script

Tags: go, installation, package

I have installed go package. When I go to the instance(VM) and run the command 
`go get github.com/linkedin/Burrow` from a terminal/cmd it is downloading both "src" & "bin" folder under user home directory. But when I run the same command by setting GOPATH in a shell script, it is only downloading the "src" folder but not generating "bin" folder.

```
SOURCE_DIR="/opt/burrow"
export GOPATH=$SOURCE_DIR/go
go get $BURROW_REPO
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4):

Use `go install` command ([Compile and install packages and dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)).

That command download `src` to `$GOPATH` and build it to `$GOBIN`.

Answer (score 4):

GOBIN may not be set at the moment.

- You can check by `go env GOBIN`. if its empty so you must set with `export GOBIN=$(go env GOPATH)/bin`
- Also, for calling binary files from your terminal, you need to use `go install` command. This will create related bin file under GOBIN path.

Comment: A slightly improved way to update the `GOBIN` environment variable would be to run the following: `go env -w GOBIN="$(go env GOPATH)/bin"`. From `go help environment` in `go1.21`: "[...] Defaults changed using 'go env -w' are recorded in a Go environment configuration file stored in the per-user configuration directory [...]". This would allow it to persist in your environment between restarts for example.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on here.

The first point of your confusion is that `go get` *does not download* neither "src" nor "bin": Go packages are always contain only source code, and they typically does not contain the "src" directory in their file and directory hierarchies.
Instead, these directories are artefacts of the the Go toolchain.

The second point of confusion is that since Go 1.8, the Go toolchain uses a [fallback value](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#gopath) for the `GOPATH` environment variable if that is not set, and on Unix-like systems it defaults to the directory named "go" under the "home" directory of the user executing the `go` command.
If this directory is missing, the toolchain will create it.

Hence my stab at your problem is that you have some sort of permissions problem: when `GOPATH` is unset, "$HOME/go" is used — with whatever value `$HOME` expands to for the current user; when you set `GOPATH` by hand, something prevents creation of the "bin" directory under `$GOPATH`.

There's another possibility: you also set the `GOBIN` environment variable, which, when set, overrides the usual location used to install binaries built by `go install` (and `go get`).
You might study the output of `go help environment` to read more on the subject.

In either case, the most sensible path forward is to run `go install` with the `-x` command-line option and see where the command tries to put the generated executable image, and why this fails (if at all).
You might study the output of `go help install` and `go help build` to read more on the subject.

---

You might also consider forcing usage of Go modules for your particular case:
running `GO111MODULES=on go get github.com/linkedin/Burrow` would work like five times faster for your use case.
Be sure to study the output of `go help modules` and `go help mod-get` first.

Answer (score 0):

`bin` folder or `src` folders are not automatically created for you by the `go get` command. Here are the standard steps creating a new project in go assuming this the first time you are creating  a project in go:

1. Under your workspace directory, create a project directory, say "project1" bin, src directories.
2. Set GOPATH, GOBIN:

   `export GOPATH=~/workspace/project1/`

   `export GOBIN=~/workspace/project1/bin`
3. Now if you need just the source code, do a `go get github.com/linkedin/Burrow`
   or if you need a binary do a `go install github.com/linkedin/Burrow`

The binary will be stored under ~/workspace/project1/bin and source code under ~/workspace/project1/

Same steps would apply either if your creating your project through a make file or terminal